# Passing a custom variable to the PayPal API

Tags: paypal

Gday All,

I am developing a site that uses PayPal to take online payments.

I need to be able to send my client an email with the link to PayPal in order to pay.

In this link I need a way to set a unique value (for example bookingId) that I can use to add the receipt number to the correct booking via PayPal's payment notification feature.

Does anyone know what custom value I can set in order to achieve this?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "item_name" field will be displayed to the user and can be set to whatever you like. I use it for conference registration ID's, while using item_number to track what was actually purchased.

Comment: All of the input fields can be hidden (type="hidden") or not (type="text" or whatever).

Comment: Well, yes, obviously in the display form. But some pass-thru variables are displayed on the receipt to the user and others are just pass-thru, invisible to the user but come back to you in IPN

Answer (score 1):

Use Invoice field.

Comment: Do you use it? Invoice is notified back in IPN? Where is the doc about this do you know? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following passthrough variables:

- custom
- item_number or item_number_x
- invoice

See page 409 in the PayPal Website Payments Standard Integration Guide:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

for details.